# Error when running winrm in jenkins pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins, winrm

```
Connecting to remote server 172.18.32.39 failed with the following error message : The WinRM client 
14:53:09  cannot process the request. Default authentication may be used with an IP address under the following conditions: the 
14:53:09  transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit credentials are provided. Use 
14:53:09  winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. For more 
14:53:09  information on how to set TrustedHosts run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the 
14:53:09  about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

I'm getting the above winrm error when the `test-wsman` command is called from my build node against my test node.  When I manually run the `test-wsman` command from the build node against the test node, it works.  I guess besides that oddity, has anyone had success resolving the above error?  Is there any way I can get more output from winrm to troubleshoot this?

Comment: When you manually run the command on the node are you signed in with the same user that owns the Jenkins agent ( assuming it’s a permanent agent )?

Comment: Yes I authenticate using the exact same service account

Answer (score 0):

## Add Host to TrustedHosts

Can you run the following commands in Powershell on the node that the pipeline is running on

```
winrm quickconfig
winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="172.18.32.39”}
```

Afterwards try running the pipeline again. Also, can you verify that you are running the test-wsman cmdlet from the same user that’s running it when it’s ran via the pipeline?